# maxSession configuration prevention for special users

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am new in spring security and have a question about session management in spring security. 
I have configured my application like this to prevent login by a user name more than once in a specific moment:

```
<bean id="sas" class="security.SessionAuthenticationStrategy">
    <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
    <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

I want to know if it is possible to prevent this configuration for special users in spring security.

Comment: Here is the configuration: <bean id="sas" class="security.SessionAuthenticationStrategy"><constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/><property name="maximumSessions" value="1" /><property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true"/></bean>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by overriding `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.getMaximumSessionsForThisUser()` in a custom subclass. Quote from [it's javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.html#getMaximumSessionsForThisUser%28org.springframework.security.core.Authentication%29):

> Method intended for use by subclasses to override the maximum number of sessions that are permitted for a particular authentication. The default implementation simply returns the maximumSessions value for the bean.

Then refer to your custom implementation by:

```
<security:session-management 
  session-authentication-strategy-ref="customConcurrentSessionControlStrategy"/>
```